# Mostrar valores reales de la base de datos en datatable

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables

Me pueden ayudar en lo siguiente. Tengo 1 tabla con los siguientes datos `PRODUCTO`, `T_UNIT` y `CUNIT`: En mi resultado el `CUNIT` en mi procedure me da un 0.056 pero en mi datatable me muestra `.056`. ¿Cómo lo puedo volver en cadena en el sql para que me muestre? Estoy utilizando el DataTables | Table plug-in for jQuery.
La función en javascript es la siguiente:

```js
var tbl_ctsunitario;
function Listar_CTSUnitario(id){
    tbl_ctsunitario = $("#tabla_ctsunitario").DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "searching": {"regex":false},
        "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100,-1],[10,25,50,100, "All"]],
        "pageLength":10,
        "destroy": true,
        "async": false,
        "processing": true,
        "bPaginate":false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo":false,
        "sDom":'t',
        "ajax":{
            "url": "../controller/datos/controlador_listar_ctsunitario.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                id:id
            }
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"PRODUCTO"},
            {"data":"T_UNIT"},
            {"data":"CUNIT"},
        ],
        "language":idioma_espanol,
        select: true
    });
}
```

Mi procedure es el siguiente:

```
    SELECT DCA.PRODUCTO,
           CAST(SUM(VALOR) AS DECIMAL(8)) T_UNIT,
           CAST(SUM(VALOR)/(SELECT DV.PESO FROM VENTA.DETALLE_PRODUCTO_VENTA DV 
                            WHERE ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO 
                              AND DV.PRODUCTO=DCA.PRODUCTO)AS NUMERIC(8,3)) CUNIT
      FROM VENTA.DOCUMENTO_COSTOS_ADICIONALES DCA       
INNER JOIN VENTA.COSTOS_ADICIONALES CA 
        ON DCA.ID_COSTOSADICIONAL=CA.ID_COSTOADICIONAL 
     WHERE DCA.ID_DOCUMENTO=@ID_DOCUMENTO 
       AND PRODUCTO <>'TODOS'
  GROUP BY DCA.PRODUCTO
  order by PRODUCTO
```

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es cambiar el código del front-end para ajustar el formato. No cambiar el código de SQL para perder funcionalidad.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es mostrar el cero a la izquierda y estás utilizando DataTables, por qué no le pones el formato que deseas en la definición de la columna? Devolver el número como string **no** es la solución.

Comment: Lo que me dicen lo trate de hacer pero no tuve solución, pregunte y pregunte y nada , lo único que me dicen es a cambiar formato

Comment: Bueno, si nos muestras lo que intentaste, podríamos ayudarte de una mejor manera. Tal vez estás SÚPER cerca de la solución. En [este link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) puedes encontrar recursos acerca del formato de números en javascript

Comment: Subí el código de la función en javascript, espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiar el tipo de dato cuando vuelve desde la base de datos no es la solución. Lo que debes hacer es darle formato al número desde la definición de la columna con [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

Puedes intentar algo quick 'n dirty:

```
...
"columns":[
        {"data":"PRODUCTO"},
        {"data":"T_UNIT"},
        {
          "data":"CUNIT",
          render: function (data, type, item, row) {
              return parseFloat(data); // parseFloat pone los ceros a la izquierda del punto decimal.
          } 
        },
    ],

   .... // el resto de tu código
```

Inténtalo y me dices qué tal te fue

Comment: Me dice que: Se esperaba una asignación de propiedad. en la ], era por q faltaba un }, Muchas gracias por la ayuda, estaba batallando con eso

Comment: Cierto. lo voy a corregir. Listo. Gracias!